# Write a program using streams - Get the elements which whose occurence is not equal to it's value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

For Ex:

```
A = {1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5}
```

Output: {1,2,5}

```
1 is occured 1's
2 is occured twice
3 does not occcured thrice
and so on.
```

I have tried to create the hashmap of occurences.
But not sure how to continue the stream and return values which satisfy condition i.e **{1,2,5}**

```
List<Integer> words = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5);
System.out.println(frequencyMap(words.stream()));

public static <Integer > Map < Integer, Integer > frequencyMap(Stream < Integer > elements) {
    return (Map<Integer, Integer>) elements.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), HashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Comment: The condition in the question is negated: {1, 2, 5] are values that are **equal** to their occurrences.

Comment: Don’t insert typecasts when the type doesn’t fit. `Collectors.counting()` uses `long` to count, hence, the resulting map is a `Map<Integer, Long>`. Further, do not declare a type variable `<Integer >` with your method. It should be `public static Map<Integer, Long> frequencyMap(Stream<Integer> elements) { return elements.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), HashMap::new, Collectors.counting())); }` though it’s debatable whether you need a method for this single statement at all. Your expected result contradicts the question’s title, by the way, which says “**not equal**”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you need to use `filter` like this:

```
List<Integer> result = words.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(entry.getValue()))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .toList();
```

1. Count occurrences: counts how many times each number appears in the list (words).
2. Filter by count: Keeps only the numbers that appear the same number of times as their value.

Comment: I want to understand how summingInt(x->1) is working here

Comment: I would prefer using `entry.getKey().intValue() == entry.getValue().intValue()` in the case `Number`s are not cached...

Comment: @AshikaJinturkar summingInt will sum every value produced by the lambda for each entering element of the downstream. Here: each counts 1.